# Removing a table row using jquery, fading and changing color slightly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that when clicked, gets the row in the table that was clicked on.

```
$("#someId").remove();
```

I want to highlight the row that is being deleted, and fade it out (it is being deleted).

Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

I tried a fadeout with remove, but that didn't achieve what I wanted.

```
$("#someId").fadeOut("slow").remove();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to do highlighting, you'll need to check out [color animations](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations).  There is an official [JQuery color plugin](http://jquery.com/plugins/project/color) that you can get in order to do color change animations with the `animate` function.  Once you have it, you should be able to accomplish everything in a manner similar to this:

```
$("#someId").animate( {backgroundColor:'yellow'}, 1000).fadeOut(1000,function() {
    $('#someId').remove();
});
```

Comment: You'll need to put .remove() within the callback of fadeOut().

Answer (score 2):

The highlight part, I don't know, but the fade out part:

```
$("someId").fadeOut(1000,function()
{
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Which does a callback:
http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the color of the row without any color transition effect
you could add a class to the row being deleted before starting the delete process.

```
  $("#someId").addClass('hilite').fadeOut('slow', function() {
     $('#someId').remove();
  });
```

where you would have defined hilite as

```
.hilite{ background-color:orange;}
```